# Generar todos los numeros Binarios de longitud 15 con dos o un "1"

Tags: python, numpy

Buenas mi duda es como genero todas las combinaciones binarias de longitud 15 que tengan 1 o 2 unos, son 121 combinaciones.
La única forma que se me ocurre es:

he visto que esta la opción de `numpy` `random.permutation` que hace todas las permutaciones del `array` que le pases, pues bien he pensando en hacer esto:

```
permuta2=np.random.permutation([1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
permuta1=np.random.permutation([1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
print(permuta1)
print(permuta2)
```

y hacer la unión de esos 2 `arrays` mas el de todo 0.

pero eso no me devuelve nada y he mirado en la documentación y se utiliza asi la función.

Muchas gracias y perdon.

Comment: Deberías limitar tu pregunta a un solo lenguaje y además mostrar lo que llevas al momento o es casi seguro tu pregunta termine cerrada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema con `numpy.random.permutations` es que en cada llamada retorna una posible permutación del array, de forma aleatoria, por lo que no es útil para obtener todas las posibles permutaciones.

Con Python estándar podríamos (pero no debemos...) hacer uso de `itertools.permutations` para generar las permutaciones con dos unos:

```
l = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

dos = list(list(p) for p in set(itertools.permutations(l)))
```

las de un solo uno es simple de construir con un `for in` simple:

```
uno = []
for i in range(15):
    l = [0] * 15
    l[i] = 1
    uno.append(l)
```

el problema es que este método para generar las permutaciones posibles de dos 1 es muy muy ineficiente ya que genera duplicados que han de ser eliminados, en este caso mediante el uso de un conjunto lo que lo hace impracticable.

Otra opción mucho más eficiente es generar permutaciones de índices:

```
import itertools

# Inicial, todos 0
r = [[0] * 15]

# Un solo 1
for i in range(15):
    l = [0] * 15
    l[i] = 1
    r.append(r)

# Dos 1
for i, j in itertools.combinations((range(15)), r=2):
    l = [0] * 15
    l[i] = l[j] = 1
    r.append(l)
```

Se puede implementar mediante una función generadora y usar `numpy.fromiter` para generar un array NumPy:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np



def permutations_gen(unos, seq_len):
    ir = range(seq_len)
    yield from (0 for _ in ir)
    for u in range(1, unos + 1):
        for perm_indices in itertools.combinations(ir, r=u):
            yield from (1 if indice in perm_indices else 0 for indice in ir) 


permutations = np.fromiter(permutations_gen(2, 15), dtype="int8")
permutations.shape = (len(permutations) // 15, 15)
```

Otra opción es usar SymPy y `sympy.utilities.iterables.multiset_permutations`:

```
import itertools

from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations
import numpy as np


a0 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
a1 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
a2 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])

iterator = itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    itertools.chain(
        iter([a0]),
        multiset_permutations(a1),
        multiset_permutations(a2)
        )
    )
permutations = np.fromiter(iterator, dtype="int8")
permutations.shape = (int(len(permutations) / 15), 15)
```

es una opción más genérica, pero bastante menos eficiente en este caso concreto si lo enfrentamos a la opción de generador + `numpy.fromiter`. En ambos casos obtenemos:

> ```
> >>> permutations
>
> array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1],
>        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0],
>        ...,
>        [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
>        [1, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
>        [1, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
>
> len(permutations)
> 121
> ```